# delete the markers in routing mode of MapQuest

Tags: leaflet, routing, mapquest

I am using MapQuest plugin for LeafletJS.

After it draw the map, it sets a marker on each stop point on the route, e.g: A, B, C, D, etc.

Is there a way to remove those markers, I just need blue routing lines.

In Google Maps, there is an option, such as:

```
suppressMarkers: true
```

Is there a way in MapQuest?
[image: map quest map]

Comment: remove the layer https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4